# How to grey out checkboxes that aren't checked?

Tags: javascript

I have unordered lists of checkbox input.Once an input is checked I want the rest to be greyed out with the option of checking another input that will also be highlighted.

instead of toggling disabled, add/remove class grey

The JS in my snippet is the closest related example I could find but this doesn't suit my purpose as it disables checkboxes I just want them grey

```js
function ckChange(ckType){
    var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType.name);
    var checked = document.getElementById(ckType.id);
    if (checked.checked) {
      for(var i=0; i < ckName.length; i++){

          if(!ckName[i].checked){
              ckName[i].disabled = true;
          }else{
              ckName[i].disabled = false;
          }
      } 
    }
    else {
      for(var i=0; i < ckName.length; i++){
        ckName[i].disabled = false;
      } 
    }    
}
```

```css
input {
opacity: 1;
}

input.grey {
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress1" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 1
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress2" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 2
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 3
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress4" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 4
</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: "with the option of checking another input that will also be highlighted" I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: instead of toggling disabled, add/remove class grey (which you've already created CSS for) ... `ckName[i].classList.add('grey');` or `ckName[i].classList.remove('grey');`

Comment: Why are you not just using `input[disabled=true]` for this?

Comment: I don't want any checkboxes to be disabled ever

Answer (score 1):

You coule use `add/remove` class instead off set disabled

Moreover, on uncheck, check if all is currently unchecked, if that, remove grey for all, else add grey for the checked

```js
function onChecked(ckName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
    if (!ckName[i].checked) {
      ckName[i].classList.add('grey')
    } else {
      ckName[i].classList.remove('grey')
    }
  }
}

function onUnchecked(ckName) {
  const allUnchecked = [...ckName].every(el => !el.checked)
  if (allUnchecked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
      ckName[i].classList.remove('grey')
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
      if (!ckName[i].checked) {
        ckName[i].classList.add('grey')
      }
    }

  }
}

function ckChange(ckType) {
  var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType.name);
  var checked = document.getElementById(ckType.id);
  if (checked.checked) {
    onChecked(ckName)
  } else {
    onUnchecked(ckName)
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  opacity: 1;
}

input.grey {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress1" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress2" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 2
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 3
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress4" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 4
  </li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much! The only thing is I would like to work out how to grey out the label too :)